# What is the source that the "skies open up" on Shavuat night?

Tags: minhag, shavuos

I remember having been taught that the "skies open up" on Shavuot and that there is a tradition to go outside on the night of Shavuot and do personal tefilot at night.

I can attest to certain to tefilot that were answered quite specifically

Whenever I have mentioned this to others, they are not familiar, so I just decided to google for it and this came up:
https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/36435?lang=bi

where it says:

> The sense of preparation for Sinai is heightened by a mystical tradition holding that the skies open up during this night for a brief instant. At that very moment, we are told, God will favorably answer any prayer.

I am wondering about the source of this mystical tradition and if others have the customs to go outside and daven on the night of Shavuot.

I am also wondering if I somehow conflated ideas and whether the "go outside" part is actually part of the custom.

Comment: I've heard of this custom specifically at midnight

Comment: K'TonTon wasn't the original source? https://books.google.com/books?id=7zKCDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT371&lpg=PT371&dq=K%27TonTon+shavuto+gate&source=bl&ots=cZ4qojZmUT&sig=ACfU3U3nwczNYuIUr4Tdnel1t2XMRbN5FQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwik8Yjiuv_3AhUdmYQIHQd3AA4Q6AF6BAgjEAM#v=onepage&q=K'TonTon%20shavuto%20gate&f=false

Comment: @rosends I like that! If I'm not mistaken, the Shalah writes about some sort of heavenly experience when staying up on Shavuos -- at least as he and his cohort experienced. That (perhaps circuitously) may have influenced the K'tonton story.

Comment: @rosends I also first heard about this from Ktonton ages ago! First time I stayed up leil Shavuos as a child I hopped outside around chatzos to take a look but didn't see anything.  Maybe I'm not on a high enough madreiga.

Comment: Most likely connection to Shavuos is 1st pasuk of Yechezkel "נִפְתְּחוּ הַשָּׁמַיִם" from haftara of the 1st day which I imagine is supposed to connect us with the revelation at Sinai. A concept of pirsum haneis is mentioned re: Shavuos / matan Torah in מגילה כד. תוד"ה ואם היו likely due to that revelation.

Wondering if another hint is Tehillim 78:23,24 "וְדַלְתֵי שָׁמַיִם פָּתָח. וַיַּמְטֵר עֲלֵיהֶם מָן לֶאֱכֹל". The מן has a strong connection to the korban ha'omer lashon עמר appears in the parsha of מן six times while 4 times for korban ha'omer/sefira/Shavuos. They seem intertwined.

Comment: Possibly from here? https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.63.19?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi

Comment: Thanks everybody for validating that this is a thing. Neat about how it's in K'tonton. I  guess I'm looking for an actual source, like some sefer where it explicitly describes the custom.